# Flush trim bits too short for 1/4in router

Tags: router, router-bit

I have a trim router with a 1/4in shank size and need to flush trim plywood that is 30mm thick. All flush trim bits that I could find which are long enough are for 1/2in shank routers? What are my options and which one should I go with?

1. I though about buying a 1/4in to 1/2in adapter, but I am worried that the adapter may be too wide. This is the 1/2 flush trim bit I set my eyes on: https://www.freudtools.com/products/44-108. As for an adapter, I would get something generic from Amazon.
2. A shorter 1/4in flush trim bit and an extension, so the bearing can reach the reference surface to glide on. Once the first pass is done, I would move the flush trim bit up (now riding on the first pass' trimmed surface) and so on.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. *"...and which one should I go with?"* ! You're an experienced SEer, you know that *all Answers equally valid* queries are specifically against the guidelines. You're also presenting two solutions and asking for respondents to pick from them, which is basically an X-Y problem.... Please re-frame the Q so that you put the problem front and centre, present the options you've come up with so far and ask for *other* solutions, rather than for people to pick between them (because that's a choice for you, and you alone, to make).

Comment: Something like this: https://www.amazon.com/Nikou-Router-Bits-Straight-Woodworking/dp/B07PYNRBN4

Comment: Option 2 will work in a pinch. A particularly long 1/4" bit might deflect if you push it hard. Option 3 is, "buy more routers". (Porter Cable 690 routers, for instance, come up on the local used boards very regularly, and are pretty bulletproof.)

Answer (score 3):

Extensions and adapters,etc. are just going to get in your way I think. Get a bit with a longer cutting surface:
[image]

[https://www.amazon.com/Nikou-Router-Bits-Straight-Woodworking/dp/B07PYNRBN4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PYNRBN4)

*This is an "almost random" example, not an endorsement or specific product recommendation.*